# table needs to be fixed during scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 tables and one of them I want to be fix after scroll more then specific distance

```
    var distance = $("#thead").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      var wdistance = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (wdistance > distance) {

      };
   })
```

demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HmFW7/3/)

I want to say when this "if" is correct then position of div with "thead" id become fixed on top of the other tables when scrolling the page. and after the div with id "first" is finish then `<div id="thead"></div>` come back to previous place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `.fixed` class and add/remove that to/from the `#thead` element, as follows:

**CSS**

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; } /* Tiny reset for removing paddings and margins */

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Note that, you have to remove the padding/margin from the `<body>` element to adjust the width of each column (when the `#thead` is positioned).

Or use the same padding/margin for the positioned `#thead` element as well.

```javascript
var $table = $("#thead"),
    $window = $(window),
    distance = $table.offset().top;

$window.scroll(function () {
    var wdistance = $window.scrollTop();

    if (wdistance > distance) {
        $table.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $table.removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/HmFW7/4/)**.

Comment: your codes are correct but It doesn't worked in my layout. I didnt write the layout myself so face with lots of problem which I dont have any idea why they are happening

Comment: @mimi I just used your jsfiddle demo to answer the question. If it's not your layout, you should update the fiddle with your exact code then.

Comment: I find the problem :D because of z-index I cant see the table when scrolling !!! thanks